# Vectors, gather/scatter and sparse arrays

Tags: gpu, vectorization, sparse-matrix, cpu-architecture, gpgpu

According to *Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach*, vector processors, both classic ones like Cray and modern ones like Nvidia, provide gather/scatter to improve performance on sparse arrays, where the array is in sparse form in memory and gathered to dense form in vector registers.

It seems to me if the array is so sparse – the density of nonzero elements so low – that it would be inefficient to represent it in dense form in memory, then it must also be inefficient to represent it in dense form in vector registers. For example, if 99% of entries are zero, then representing it in dense form in memory would waste 98% of the memory... but would waste 99% of the vector register capacity and arithmetic operations! That's high enough that you would be better off just processing it with scalar operations. If 75% of entries are zero, then you would be better off to represent it in dense form in memory and avoid the nonsequential gather/scatter operations.

What is the typical density of nonzero elements where gather/scatter is used? Is it very common for it to be in some sweet spot where this duality makes sense - in which case, what workloads generate this particular density range so often - or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: As I understand it, sparse means "sparse in memory" as opposed to "continuous in memory" (this happens if you have a matrix in the wrong column-row major format). Is that what the book is referring to? Sparse is not in the mathematical sense, rather in the representation sense. Zero elements are still necessary for the correct computation and unless the algorithm can explicitly skip them, they are not really different from any other non zero element.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Right, my point is that if you have some zero elements, it makes sense to use 'continuous in memory' representation. Only if practically all your elements are zero does it make sense to use 'sparse in memory' representation, and then it doesn't make sense to use 'continuous in vector registers'. It's not about column/row-major; the processor feature dealing with that is called strided memory access, a distinct thing from the semi-random pattern of gather/scatter.

Comment: A strided access is a gather/scatter access but with unit indexes. I still don't see how zero elements come into play. For me it's about pre-existing formats. I know that SG can be used for AES SBox implementation.

Comment: A sparse array has to record, in some format or other, not only the value, but it's location/indices.  Potentially that's 3x as much memory per nonzero element.  Processing is also more complicated.  Iteration through a dense form just requires stepping the index (strided stepping for multidimensional arrays).  Iteration through the sparse form requires look up in 2 or 3 dense arrays.

Comment: A useful datapoint to answer to question can be found at https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html. It recommends using cuSparse library for matrices with >95% zeros. There should be a trial and error to determine the exact sweet spot for your application and hardware where switching from sparse to dense representation provides better performance.

Comment: @instinct71 Thanks! That is clear that beyond a certain degree of sparsity, matrices should be stored sparse in memory. But it doesn't say whether it goes with Hennessey and Patterson, in switching them to dense representation on loading into vector registers?

Comment: Without dedicated hardware to manage math with data in sparse representation, converting to dense representation in datapath is the way to perform math. Although, in a way, scatter/gather is *dedicated* HW, that delays the sparse->dense conversion until we really need it (i.e. ALUs needing registers with operand values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating comment to answer.

A useful datapoint to answer to question can be found at docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html. It recommends using cuSparse library for matrices with >95% zeros. There should be a trial and error to determine the exact sweet spot for your application and hardware where switching from sparse to dense representation provides better performance.

Without dedicated hardware to manage math with data in sparse representation, converting to dense representation in datapath is the way to perform math. Although, in a way, scatter/gather is dedicated HW, that delays the sparse->dense conversion until we really need it (i.e. ALUs needing registers with operand values).